# Angular 2: How to use and import ng2-slider-component?

Tags: angular, systemjs

Note: I only installed ng2-slider-component, not any of its dependencies individually.

I am doing this for my main app component's template:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'slider-cmp',
    template: `
        <h1>Slider Cmp</h1>
        <ng2-slider 
    min="6"
    max="23"
    startValue="9"
    endValue="21"
    stepValue="2"
    [normalHandlerStyle]="{ 'background-color': 'green'}"
    [slidingHandlerStyle]="{
          'border-radius': '9px',
          'background-color': 'red'
    }">
</ng2-slider>
    `
  })
```

I have this in my systemjs.config.js file.

Some of the map variable:

```
'ng2-slider-component': 'node_modules/ng2-slider-component'
```

Some of the packages variable:

```
'ng2-slider-component': {

    main: 'ng2-slider.component.system.js',
    defaultExtension: 'system.js'
  }
```

I get this error:
Can't bind to 'normalHandlerStyle' since it isn't a known property of 'ng2-slider'.

1. If 'ng2-slider' is an Angular component and it has 'normalHandlerStyle' input, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'ng2-slider' is a Web Component then add "CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA" to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.

How do I modify the AppModule - what should be the import statements at the top of the AppModule file, and what declarations and/or providers? Is the systemjs.config.js file correct, I basically followed whatever I was told to do here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-slider-component

Comment: try it using `[attr.normalHandlerStyle]=...`

Comment: also if `ng2-slider` is module than import this in declaration otherwise it is component than list down in the imports section of AppModule.